# How to drop or rename database?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wrongly created a snowflake database name with an extra dot:

> THAT_COOL_SAMPLE_STUFF.

How can I drop or rename the database?

Answer (score 0):

you can rename it:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE IF EXISTS "THAT_COOL_SAMPLE_STUFF." RENAME TO "THAT_COOL_SAMPLE_STUFF"
```

you can escape special characters in snowflake (and most of dbms) by using double quote.

Comment: @BaskarGanapathi you are welcome , please accept / upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

If a databse name contain special character(here '.') then you need to qoute it with `""`:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "THAT_COOL_SAMPLE_STUFF.";
```

Alternatively you could drop it from WebUI under Databases section.